# Router's associated IP/MAC: associated client's name not resolved?

Tags: networking, router, mac-address

The picture below is a partial screenshot of IP&MACs associated to our company's router. In the first line the client device name is 'resolved' as 'RNP931A07'. However, in lines 2 and 3 you can see that no name was found and some kind of fallback to a name like "Unknown_...." is done.

[image]

**Question**

We would like to have the 'real' device names on that list, that is quite convenient if you have to check who's who.

How does MAC to device name association works ? What can be done on the client machines to 'correctly declare' their names ?

Thnx

Comment: Where does that screenshot come from? What OS, etc., are you running?

Comment: “How does MAC to device name association work?” – Not at all, in fact. This information has to be inferred from other sources like DHCP requests, NetBIOS messages, ...

Comment: Nokia router modem G-240W-A ALCL G-240W-A, screenshot from the router's admin page 'GPON'.

Comment: Daniel B, is there a way for me to make the client that "do not have another source like DHCP requests..." have one to share their names ? (weird quesiton)